# What's the purpose of the format provider in ParseExact() of DateTime and DateTimeOffset?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimeoffset, iformatprovider

Let us consider [DateTimeOffset.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.parseexact?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.DateTimeOffset.ParseExact)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0#System_DateTimeOffset_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_)

```
public static DateTime ParseExact (
    string s, 
    string format, 
    IFormatProvider? provider, 
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles style
);
```

The expected format is already described via the `format` parameter, so what's the purpose of the `provider`parameter? Can anyone please give an example how different `provider` values can lead to different results?

Comment: I would expect it has something to do with text elements of certain date formats. E.g., "12 Jun 2020" might mean 2020-06-12 in English but something completely different in another.

Comment: Different cultures will use different values for things such as month names. 'Jul` might be July to you, but in France it's not.

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of various elements of a custom datetime format string depend on the format provider.

Example:

```
var aString = "12 avr. 2021";
var gbCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
var frCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");

var canParseGb = 
    DateTime.TryParseExact(aString, "dd MMM yyyy", gbCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var gbDateTime);
var canParseFr = 
    DateTime.TryParseExact(aString, "dd MMM yyyy", frCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var frDateTime);
```

Same input string `s`, same format string `format`, different `provider`s => different results.

Answer (score 4):

For example `CultureInfo` implements `IFormatProvider`. So you can pass a culture which has it's own formatting rules apart from your provided format string.

Also note that the format string can contain specifiers that will behave differently with different cultures/format-providers like the ["/" custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN#dateSeparator):

```
CultureInfo deCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE"); // german
CultureInfo frCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR"); // french
// works because / is replaced with the passed culture's date-separator which is . in germany
DateTime dateDe = DateTime.ParseExact("25.02.2021", "dd/MM/yyyy", deCulture, DateTimeStyles.None); 
// works not since french use / as date-separator
DateTime dateFr = DateTime.ParseExact("25.02.2021", "dd/MM/yyyy", frCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

As Magnetron has commented the same applies to the  [":" custom time format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN#timeSeparator)

Comment: Also [":" for time separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN#timeSeparator)

Answer (score 2):

Different cultures will use different values for things such as month names and days of the week. `Jul` might be July to you, but in France it's not. For example:

```
var frenchDate = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("1 févr. 2020", "d MMM yyyy", 
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"));

var englishDate = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("1 Feb 2020", "d MMM yyyy", 
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

All of these details can be seen in the `CultureInfo` object, for example `fr-FR` looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is quite clear on this:

> The particular date and time symbols and strings used in `input` are defined by the `formatProvider` parameter...